# Automapper, mapping multiple properties into 1 w/o ValueResolver

Tags: automapper

My current code is working:

```cs
map.ForMember(x => x.Address, m => m.ResolveUsing(l => {
    var engine = new MappingEngine((IConfigurationProvider)cfg);
    var adress = engine.Map<AddressDto>(l.ContactInfo);
    engine.Map(l.Address, adress);
    return adress;
}));
```

but I thought there might be another way, something like:

```cs
map.ForMember(x => x.Address, m => m.MapFrom(x => x.ContactInfo));
map.ForMember(x => x.Address, m => m.MapFrom(x => x.Address));
```

But the last ForMember seems to override the existing map.

I'm trying to combine Address and ContactInfo properties into a single object on ListingDto.Address.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var map = Mapper.CreateMap<Listing, ListingDto>();
    var cfg = Mapper.Configuration;
    map.ForMember(x => x.Address, m => m.ResolveUsing(l => {
        var engine = new MappingEngine((IConfigurationProvider)cfg);
        var adress = engine.Map<AddressDto>(l.ContactInfo);
        engine.Map(l.Address, adress);
        return adress;
    }));

    Mapper.CreateMap<Address, AddressDto>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Latitude, x => x.Ignore());
    Mapper.CreateMap<ContactInfo, AddressDto>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Street, x=> x.Ignore());

    Mapper.Map<ListingDto>(new Listing{ 
    Name="Foo", 
    Address = new Address{Street = "Street"},
    ContactInfo = new ContactInfo{ Latitude = "latitude"}}).Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Listing{        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public ContactInfo ContactInfo {get;set;}
}

public class ContactInfo{
    public string Latitude {get;set;}
}
public class Address{
    public string Street {get;set;}
}


public class AddressDto{
    public string Latitude {get;set;}
    public string Street {get;set;}
}

public class ListingDto{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AddressDto Address {get;set;}
}
```

.Dump() <-- is from linqpad to output

Answer (score 7):

Something like this should work:

```
.ForMember(x => x.Address, o => o.MapFrom(
    s => new AddressDto { 
        Latitude = s.ContactInfo.Latitude, 
        Street = s.Address.Street }));
```